# cordova-plugin-camera: Crash wesh error “No Image Selected” on IOS device

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-camera

I have an ionic app with cordova-plugin-camera installed.

(@ionic-native/camera: 5.12.0 & cordova-plugin-camera: 4.1.0)

It works great on Android, and works also great when i take a picture on IOS but when i cancel the action of taking pictures on IOS (camera, gallery or pictures), i got the error :

> ERROR:  No Image Selected 2019-11-29 12:42:03.739984+0100 App -[NSNull
>   UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e66639a0 App***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull UTF8String]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e66639a0'
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Then the app completely freze and i have to restart it.

Any idea on how to fix it is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've been able to fix it.

Seems like firebase plugin dont know the exception type sent when you cancel. So in logError() i just commented the call to [CrashlyticsKit recordError:error];, and it works.

I have no experience in ios / or ionic dev, so i just know if its not a decent way to fix it, but i have to idea how to fix it correctly. 
Any advices are welcomed